# How to change grub.conf after adding init=/bin/bash

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, grub

I added `init=/bin/bash` in grub.conf file, so my linux system is always entering bash when booted.
Is there a way to change the grub.conf file so that I can boot Linux again.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** `e`, remove `init=`. `ctrl+x`

One of the options is to temporary change grub entry to fix booting problem, edit grub.conf and update-grub.

1. Keep `shift` pressed during boot (if you don't see grub menu)
2. **Press `e` to edit menu item**
3. Edit to **remove** `init=...` phrase
4. **Press `ctrl+x` to boot**
5. Now you can edit `grub.conf`
6. Run `update-grub`
7. reboot

Answer (score -1):

After making changes to grub file run :

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will update your grub

Comment: How do I open grub.conf from bash ?

Answer (score -1):

**TLDR;** `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda`

It's possible that after booting with `init=/bin/bash` your filesystem is in **readonly** state. That means you cannot modify any config files.

Try to **remount** it as `read-write` (my disk is at `/dev/sda`). If you don't know the name, use `lsblk`

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda
```

`update-grub` will not work if `/boot` is not mounted

```
mount /boot
```

Now you can edit `grub.conf` and run `update-grub`